# How do I create a histogram chart in Excel with class interval bins?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

I am trying to create a histogram to show the full set of 100 compensations using class intervals (i.e. bins) of width 4 (0-4, 4-8, etc.)

However, after using Data Analysis->Histogram to create the graph, I can't figure out how to change the bins to be of width 4 instead of 16.

What it looks like now:
[image: What it looks like now]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least two ways around this, two that I know are described below.

1. When you're creating your histogram the first field is to introduce the input range of your data. The second field allows you to define a list with the bin sizes.

[image: Histogram screen]

2. After you've created a histogram, right-click on the X axis and Click on Format-axis. You can then define the bin size as well.